# powerquery filtering data in import time

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a data file I want to import into excel

```
alpha,customer,10
alpha,town,12
bravo,customer,6
bravo,cars,5
charly,cats,5
```

(actual file is about 15 columns and 1000's lines)

I can import into excel using following power query

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Some\path\New_File_1.txt"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Type modifié" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Type modifié"
```

Is there any way to import only lines with `alpha` values in first column ?

I know I can filter in excel, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

When you're loading the data, click 'Transform Data', as shown above.

In the PowerQuery Editor, filter column1 for the required value:

[image]

Click 'Close & Load' and your filtered data will be loaded into the spreadsheet:

[image]

Comment: thanks, that did the trick. this add following line in powerquery text `#"Lignes filtrées" = Table.SelectRows(#"Type modifié", each [Column1] = "alpha")`